# Discord bot randomly sending ad links

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.io

I'm making a discord bot and am new to discord.io. My bot randomly sends ad messages every 1-2 hours or so. I am working with only one file (bot.js) and none of it mentions the ad message. The message is somewhat like this:
"@everyone I have good news :flame:!
(adlink)"
I cleared my dependencies and reinstalled about 3 times now, and searched the entire project. Not one file has any of this in it. Can someone help me find the root of this problem please?

In the past, I had a file called testbot.js which used discord.js instead of discord.io, but I deleted that one. It shouldn't have any effect on the current problem, right?

This is how I start the bot if it's useful at all:

```
var bot = new Discord.Client({
   token: auth.token,
   autorun: true
});
bot.on('ready', function (evt) {
    logger.info('Connected');
    logger.info('Logged in as: ');
    logger.info(bot.username + ' - (' + bot.id + ')');

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but it sounds like someone may have compromised your Discord Developer App account or have gotten access to your token, and is running the bot with the ad code somewhere else. I'd suggest regenerating your token as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks, did that and it stopped sending

Answer (score 0):

You should probably reset your token, I'd assume someone hacked your discord bot.